# PayPal Request Money over API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

PayPal provides a feature to request Money over an Email-Adress and I want to call this function in my application with Rest, soap or NvP.

Now my question is there an API that I can use ? Or is there another way to archive this goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no request money API in PayPal but you may want to try invoicing API instead or PayPal.me link ( https://www.paypal.me/ ).